# Align blurred and sharp rectangles

Tags: matlab, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

Looking to align (register) and find the linear transformation between a pair of rectangular borders. One is a blurred and transformed version of the other (unknown blur kernel and a similarity transformation - rotation, translation and scale).

This is the input pair of images:

[image: sharp]
[image: blurred]

So far, I've tried registering the pair of images using both mutual information and brightness constancy. Namely, with the `imregtform` function from MATLAB's image processing toolbox. This is the best result I've been able to obtain (displaying a fused image with the blurred pixels in channels R,B and the sharp in channel G):

[image: pair]

Which is not bad but is not perfect. Note in the right side the blurriness is not symmetric around the sharp rectangles.

I'm wondering if there is any other, simpler way to do this. Note, that I have complete control over the pattern! If anyone has an idea of a better pattern to use for alignment it can certainly help!

Comment: Wow you actually are getting quite good results. I would suggest SIFT or SURF, but probably you are alraedy over the accuracy of those two...

Comment: I honestly don't think you can do any better.  Maybe do an interest point detection approach as per @AnderBiguri , but this is honestly really good so far!

Comment: I too doubt you can get much better results than this, and yet, if your intention is to make this from scratch, you could try using image moments ('regionprops') to normalize the size and direction, followed by a (normalized) cross correlation to register. SURF/SIFT on such a simple image seems a bit of an overkill for me (+doubt it will work).

Answer (score 0):

you can try affine registration, resize the bigger image and use DROP http://www.mrf-registration.net/deformable/index.html, it does more sophisticated stuff like discrete optimization using patch based matching, followed by b-spline interpolation to deform images

Comment: That's an impressive piece of software, and it successfully registered the images in the question! Thanks! However, I'm in need of finding the linear transformation between the two (I haven't been specific enough about this so I updated the question). So I cannot use the non-rigid transformation generated by the software

Comment: There is also an affine registration option at the top? Moreover when you set the lambda value to a very large number, its essentially a linear transformation, as the pairwise potential is so high that it does not allow deformations

Comment: OK, cool. Will I be able to eventually get the affine transformation 3x3 matrix?

Comment: It prints the 3x3 matrix if you chose the affine version of it (I am not sure, if they still have it there)

Comment: There does not seem to be an 'affine' version ([screen shot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ufj7nk9graoo0w1/drop2d.png)). The only outputs are the deformed image and the deformation field, which is to my understanding the entire mesh grid. This is a very impressive tool though.

Comment: ohh, may be they did not push an update, unfortunately I can't share the source code...